# Nginx not found, but server display "504 Gateway Time-out" (WHM/cpanel)

Tags: nginx, centos, whm, http-status-code-504

Server working with WHM/Cpanel, and when long time php scripts executing, server display "504 Gateway Time-out".

But I can't find any nginx files on server...
Tried:

find / -name nginx.conf

whereis nginx

ps -lA | awk '$12 == "?" {print $4, $14}'

nginx -V

OS: CentOS

sites using cloudflare

Answer (score 0):

You are not using nginx on your server as web server. You have enable cloudflare for your account and cloudflare is using nginx and that is the reason your site is showing nginx error.

Try to update your webserver setting and check server logs so that you can find out root cause of this issues.